# Find the recursive formula for the number of different barcodes of width n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Barcodes are created following the rules:

- codes are constructed from white and black bars, each bar 1 or 2 units wide
- black and white bars are set alternately
- each code begins and ends with a black bar

Find the recursive formula for the number of codes of width n.
Width equals sum of all widths of the bars.

I found a solution that might be correct. Suppose the number of barcodes of width n equals f(n). Then:

$f(0)=0$
$f(1)=1$ (b)
$f(2)=1$ (bb)
$f(3)=1$ (b-w-b)

Now let's consider 4 cases:
Case 1: Code starts and ends with a black bar of width 1. Notice that between them we have another code of width n-2 which has to begin and end with white bars. If we reverse its colour it has black bars on its edges. So, the number of codes in this case equals f(n-2).

b-(reversed code of n-2 width)-b

Cases 2,3,4: (by analogy)
bb - (reversed code of n-3 width) - b
b - (reversed code of n-3 width) - bb
bb - (reversed code of n-4 width) - bb

So we sum up all the cases:
$f(n)=f(n-2)+2f(n-3)+f(n-4), n>3$

Comment: What is the width in this case? The number of bars? The sum of all the widths of the bars?

Comment: The sum of all widths of the bars

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I added my idea for a solution.

Comment: I agree with your recursion equation.